# Spring WebSocket Stomp headers are set on client side. Is this safe?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-websocket, stomp

```
stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
    showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
},{'durable': true});
```

As  seen in code piece above;
If I set the durable header while subscribing a topic, the queue created on RabbitMQ becomes durable.  So, I understand from this, the client is able to change queue settings. **Is this safe**, **if not** is there a way to **preven**t it? By the way durable header just for example. My question applies to other headers as well.

Environment: Spring Boot / RabbitMQ with STOMP

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not the behavior is "safe" depends completely on the use-case. In some use-cases it would be safe. In other use-cases it would not be safe.

See the [RabbitMQ security documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html) for details on how to control what users can and cannot do on the broker.